# Declare a variable in oracle in a python SQL query

Tags: python, oracle

I am porting code from SQL Server to Oracle.

```
DECLARE @DispatchCount int,
@HeadCount int;

SELECT @DispatchCount = (
    select 200 -- business query would replace sample
);

select @HeadCount = (
    select 50 -- business query would replace sample 
);

select @DispatchCount / @HeadCount;
```

I tried oracle declare syntax.

```
DECLARE
    head_count INTEGER;

BEGIN

select 100 as DUMMY into head_count from dual;
dbms_output.put_line(head_count);

END;
```

I am querying a read only oracle 11g database in python from cx_oracle:

```py
cursor.execute(sql)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

This throws the error: 'not a query' on the fetchall statement.
Is there a way to declare variables in oracle that will work in a SQL query?

Comment: I see various answers so I'll just add some side comments: the `dbms_output.put_line(head_count);` line won't directly do anything in cx_Oracle unless you do some extra steps like shown in the cx_Oracle example [DbmsOutput.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/DbmsOutput.py).  The other comment is that 11g is very old.  If you are using the "XE" edition, then you should think about installing XE 18c.

Comment: Why do you need a *database* to calculate a *division* at all?

Comment: There is a list of SQL Server database statements that need to be ported to Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In oracle, One way is to use the CTE as follows:

```
with cte as 
(select 200 as dispatchcount, 50 as headcount from dual)
select dispatchcount/headcount from cte
```

If you want both variables in different table then use the multiple cte as follows:

```
with cte1 as 
(select 200 as dispatchcount from dual),
cte2 as (select 50 as headcount from dual)
select dispatchcount/headcount from cte1 , cte2
```

Comment: it would be great to have a solution that works even if dispatchcount and headcount are in different tables. in my case I will look into restructuring the query like that, thanks.

Comment: Ok, Updated the answer. Please check the updated section

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use prepared SQL statement along with dummy `dual` table, including placeholders for parameters those are stated within a tuple, through use of `cursor.fetchone()` considering your case needs to return only one row such as

```
DispatchCount=200
HeadCount=50

sql  = """
          SELECT :1 / :2
            FROM dual
       """

cursor.execute(sql,(DispatchCount,HeadCount,))
rows = cursor.fetchone()
    
print(rows[0])
```

For a table with multiple rows you can replace `fetchone()` with `fetchall()` too.

Comment: Valid answer. I accepted Popeye's answer because I need to avoid modifications to the python code.